# Firebase Read getter setter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was trying to get some data from my Firebase realtime-database as followed generally, but couldn't figure out where in the code the problem was haunting me.The following Toast statement returns with only the name but it doesn't print bmdc!

I couldn't figure out where the problem was. The code is here:

```
package com.example.abed.smit;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class  FindDocActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView SearchButton_doc;
private EditText SearchInput_doc;

private RecyclerView SearchResult_doc;

private DatabaseReference allDocdatabaseref;

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FindDoctors, FindDoctorsViewHolder>  firebaseRecyclerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_doc);

    SearchResult_doc = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.search_result_list1);
    SearchResult_doc.setHasFixedSize(true);
    SearchResult_doc.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    SearchButton_doc = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.search_people_btn1);
    SearchInput_doc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Search_box_input1);

    allDocdatabaseref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("BMDC");


    SearchButton_doc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String searchBoxInput1 = SearchInput_doc.getText().toString().trim();

            SearchDoc(searchBoxInput1);


        }
    });


}

private void SearchDoc(String searchBoxInput1) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "searching..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Query searchdoctorquery = allDocdatabaseref.orderByChild("name").startAt(searchBoxInput1).endAt(searchBoxInput1 + "\uf8ff");


    firebaseRecyclerAdapter
            = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FindDoctors, FindDoctorsViewHolder>(
            FindDoctors.class,
            R.layout.all_userdoc_display_layout,
            FindDoctorsViewHolder.class,
            searchdoctorquery

    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(FindDoctorsViewHolder viewHolder, FindDoctors model, int position) {
            /// Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),model.getName().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            viewHolder.setbmdc(model.getbmdc());
            viewHolder.setName(model.getName());
        }
    };
    SearchResult_doc.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
}

public static class FindDoctorsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View mView;

    public FindDoctorsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
    }

    public void setbmdc(String bmdc) {

        TextView Docbmdc = mView.findViewById(R.id.all_user_profile_name1);
        Docbmdc.setText(bmdc);
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        TextView Docname = mView.findViewById(R.id.all_user_profile_status1);
        Docname.setText(name);
    }

}
}
```

I used getter setter:

```
package com.example.abed.smit;

public class FindDoctors {

public String bmdc , name;

public FindDoctors()
{

}
public FindDoctors(String bmdc, String name) {
    this.bmdc =bmdc;
    this.name = name;
}

public String getbmdc() {
    return bmdc;
}

public void setbmdc(String bmdc) {
    this.bmdc = bmdc;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

Here is the result:

[image: here is the result!]

[image: Database]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that you have an incorrect getter for `bmdc` field in your model class. The correct getter should be `getBmdc()` and **not** `getbmdc()` as it is in your code now. See the capital letter `B` versus lower case letter `b`? The correct model class should look like this:

```
public class FindDoctors {
    private String bmdc, name;

    public FindDoctors() {}

    public FindDoctors(String bmdc, String name) {
        this.bmdc = bmdc;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getBmdc() { return bmdc; }

    public String getName() { return name; }
}
```

The setters are not required, are always optional because if there is no setter for a JSON property, the Firebase client will set the value directly onto the field. But if you wish to use setters, the correct setter for your field is:

```
public void setBmdc(String bmdc) {
    this.bmdc = bmdc;
}
```